# Listview not scrolling with swipe gesture on listview Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using `ListView` with `RawScrollbar`, and it is working fine. I can scroll the listview with scroll bar drag.

I want to scroll listview in both ways either through scrollbar drag or listview swipe gesture. But currently I am unable to scroll listview with swipe gesture.

```html
RawScrollbar(
          thumbColor: Colors.grey[200],
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          controller: controller,
          thickness: 17,
          radius: const Radius.circular(20),
          child: ListView.separated(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                 shrinkWrap: true,
                 controller: controller,
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 20),
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                     return Container();
                      
                 },       
               ),
          );
```

This is my code. Anyone help me please with this little issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what's the problem? It works well for me

Comment: I am using for desktop. This is desktop flutter application.

Comment: Not working for desktop.

Answer (score 1):

try add scrollbarOrientation on rawscrollbar.
For scroll Direction vertial, orientation is left or right .
For scroll Direction horizontal, orientation is top or bottom.

And remember that RawScrollbar controller is the same that ListView controller.

```
RawScrollbar(
          thumbColor: Colors.grey[200],
          scrollbarOrientation: ScrollbarOrientation.bottom,
          isAlwaysShown: true,
          controller: controller,
          thickness: 17,
          radius: const Radius.circular(20),
          child: ListView.separated(
                 scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                 shrinkWrap: true,
                 controller: controller,
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, right: 5, bottom: 20),
                 itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                     return Container();
                      
                 },       
               ),
          );
```

Comment: Already added that but it is working perfectly fine for mobile only not for desktop.

Comment: After I did some search and found this solution https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/default-scroll-behavior-drag. Adding custom scroll behavior and it is working perfectly.